# How to use 100% DIV height with HTML5?

Tags: html, css

I have tried following many articles and used many links in SO but I cannot fix my CSS of my page. The page can be seen here: http://tinyurl.com/d3ru8tf

Screenshot:

[image]

My CSS

```
html, body {
   height:100%
}

body{
   line-height:1;
   color:#454545;
   background:url(/assets/imgs/bg.png);
   font:11px Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif
}

#soul{
   display:block;
   margin:0 auto;
   width:920px;
   background:url(/assets/imgs/back.png) repeat-y right #fff;
   padding:0;
   position:relative;
   height:100%
}
```

My HMTL5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div id="soul">

          This is my content which does not sit fluid.

       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `<hr style="clear:both;" />` right before closing `</div>` of `#soul` and remove `height:100%` from `#soul` CSS.

[image]

Also, use `min-height:100%`, or better, yet, don't use that attribute at all in this case.

**Edit**

Read more about floating divs: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Also, you seem to want them to be equal in height.

[image]

Take a look at this: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid You have left and right floating divs inside #soul, thus they cannot "push" #soul to extend to proper height, plus CSS is blocking that.

Comment: Ah ok.. I have been using this method for years. Look at the left menu though, the border does not go 100%... this was my aim. `inherit` does not work with your fix

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid You need to do it otherwise, or add, perhaps, scroll (like in Google Images).

Comment: No I mean, look at left hand side menu, there is a border, I want that to fluid go down too